# How to Consume Messages from RabbitMQ as Plain Text using MassTransit?

Tags: .net, serialization, rabbitmq, messaging, masstransit

I'm working on a project where I need to consume messages from RabbitMQ using MassTransit. However, I don't want to deserialize or interpret the incoming messages as JSON. The producer's behavior is fixed, so I can't make changes there. Additionally, I'll be consuming from other queue systems in the future, so using MassTransit is essential.

Is there an existing `ISerializerFactory` in MassTransit that supports plain text consumption? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MassTransit is type-based, you'd need to build your own serializer and figure out how to wrap that plain text in a type that can be dispatched to a consumer.

Comment: When I implement a IConsumer<string> or IConsumer<byte[]> my custom IMessageDeserializer.Deserialize gets called; but afterwards it gets skipped  and no other function is called in my custom impementations. Any hints? @ChrisPatterson

Comment: ok, I guess when i go with something like `public sealed record Payload(string Data);` and implement IConsumer<Payload> i can put everything in there... is that the solution?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a type, not a System type.